# Use fields from another table as max-number-rows-with-type constrain in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id          INT(7) NOT NULL,
   restricted_type  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE type_restrictions (
   name           VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   restriction    INT NOT NULL
)
```

I want to check on insert, that there are no more than `restriction` users with `restricted_type = type_restriction.name`.

At this point I'm inserting data with this query:

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, restricted_type) SELECT <id>, <type> FROM DUAL
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM type_restrictions T
         WHERE T.name = <type> AND T.restriction < (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM users U
           WHERE U.user_id = <id> AND U.restricted_type = <type>)
       )
```

But with two or more parallel queries it is possible to end up with more users with `restricted_type` than actual restriction for this type.

Is there any way to make such constraint work? (Also, I always insert only one row per query, if it helps)

Comment: You could try to put that logic in a trigger, that throws an error if a row would violate that rule.

Comment: I already tried to put exactly logic as in `WHERE NOT EXISTS` inside `before insert` trigger, however problem still there.. With two or more parallel transactions I sometimes end up violating restriction, but trigger is silent about it. Will try it again, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `select ...` in constraint. You cannot select from table which you are inserting into in normal trigger. What you can do? Materialized view (probably, I am not sure) or compound trigger. Here is my (working) try:

```
create or replace trigger trg_users_restrict 
  for insert on users compound trigger

  type tt is table of number index by varchar2(5);
  vt tt;
  i varchar2(5);
  v_max int;

before statement is 
begin 
  for r in (select restricted_type, count(1) cnt from users group by restricted_type) 
  loop
    vt(r.restricted_type) := r.cnt;
  end loop;
end before statement;

after each row is
begin
  begin
    vt(:new.restricted_type) := vt(:new.restricted_type) + 1;
  exception when no_data_found then 
    vt(:new.restricted_type) := 1;
  end;
end after each row;

after statement is
begin
  i := vt.first;
  while i is not null loop
    select nvl(max(restriction), 0) into v_max 
      from type_restrictions where name = i;
    if vt(i) > v_max then
      raise_application_error( -20001, 
        'maximum number exceeded for restriction type ' || i );
    end if;
    i := vt.next(i);
  end loop;
end after statement;

end trg_users_restrict;
```

In `before statement` I grouped data from `users` table into collection. In `after each row` I increased proper values in collection for newly inserted row(s). In `after statement` I check if data in collection exceeds allowed ranges in table `type_restrictions`.

When two sessions insert concurent data then this which commits last causes exception.